# Spark SQL - Performance Diagnostics

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL but some queries are very slow. I would like to know how I can get some insights about why the queries are slow so that I can try to optimise the system.

Answer (score 0):

Check stages locality level and timing in drivers UI. Usually you can find it on 4040 port on driver